# Infinitely many primes that $\exists n, p\mid n!+1, n\nmid p-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $p\mid n!+1$ and $n \nmid p-1$.

This seems to be a generalization of Wilson's theorem. From first glance, $n$ must be less than $p-1$ as otherwise $p\mid 1$. Assuming only finitely many such primes doesn't seem to give any useful information that relates to Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also don't see how to use an assumption of only finitely many such primes. Instead, consider

$$k = 6j + 1, \; \; j \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

For any particular $j$, and thus $k$, if there's at least one prime $p$ with $p \mid k! + 1$ and $k \nmid p - 1$, we can use that prime $p$, with $n = k$. Otherwise, then all prime factors $p$ of $k! + 1$ have $k \mid p - 1$. Choosing any one of these primes, since $2k + 1 = 2(6j+1) + 1 = 12j + 3$ is divisible by $3$, there is then an even integer $m$ where

$$p = mk + 1, \; \; m \ge 4 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, using $k$ being odd and $k! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, we have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\prod_{i=p-k}^{p-1}i & \equiv \prod_{i=p-k}^{p-1}(-1)(p-i) \\
& \equiv (-1)^{k}\prod_{i=p-k}^{p-1}(p-i) \\
& \equiv (-1)\prod_{i=1}^{k}i \\
& \equiv (-1)k! \\
& \equiv 1 \pmod{p}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Going from the second to the third line's product, the order of factors was reversed and the indices were adjusted. Using \eqref{eq3A} and [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), we then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}i & \equiv -1 \pmod{p} \\
\left(\prod_{i=1}^{p-k-1}i\right)\left(\prod_{i=p-k}^{p-1}i\right) & \equiv -1 \pmod{p} \\
\prod_{i=1}^{p-k-1}i & \equiv -1 \pmod{p} \\
(p-k-1)! & \equiv -1 \pmod{p}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, using \eqref{eq2A}, $p \mid ((m-1)k)! + 1$. However, if $(m-1)k \mid mk$, then $m - 1 \mid m$, but this isn't possible since $\gcd(m-1,m) = 1$ and $m-1 \gt 1$. Thus, we can use this prime $p$ with $n = (m-1)k$.

As you mentioned, all primes $p$ where $p \mid n! + 1$ have $p \ge n+1$. Therefore, with $k$ increasing without bound with increasing $j$, the above shows there are infinitely many primes $p$ that meet the conditions.

Comment: What's the motivation of choosing $k=6j+1$? The only place that this is used seems to be just excluding $m=2$

Comment: @ThetaOmega I chose $k=6j+1$ so it's odd (for $(3)$ to work properly) and $2k+1$ is never prime, which is a simple way to have $m\ge 4$ in $(2)$ and, thus, I can ensure $n=(m-1)k$ *always* works in my $(4)$. Other forms of $k$ where $2k+1$ is guaranteed to not be prime will also work, with what I used in $(1)$ just happening to be fairly simple & the first one I thought of. Note for any prime $q\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $k=2qj+\frac{3q-1}{2}$ works (e.g., for $q=5$, then $k=10j+7$), and any prime $q\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $k=2qj+\frac{q-1}{2}$ works (e.g., $q=3$ in my $(1)$).